# Many problems with Anaconda installation -

Tags: python, anaconda, arcgis

I am attempting to install the Anaconda 2.7 64-bit version.  I have ArcGIS 10.5 installed on this computer, and I suspect that may be related to my issues.  ArcGIS installed a 32-bit version of python on my computer.  It seems that all of my paths for python are in C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5.  I installed Anaconda in C:\Users\aneme.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda several times in this path.  Each time, I chose to register Anaconda as my default Python 2.7.  The first time, I received this error when opening the Anaconda prompt:  DLL load failed, %1 is not a valid win32 application.  Then I uninstalled it and reinstalled it.  The next time, the Anaconda Navigator would not open, and I received a strange error, when I tried to configure a conda environment in pycharm:

> Failed to Create Interpreter Executed command: Conda C:\Users\aneme\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda.exe create -p C:\Users\aneme\Anaconda2\envs\untitled -y python=2.7 KeyError: u'pkgs_dirs'.

This is followed by a long list of files paths, and it ends with environmental variables:

> conda info could not be constructed. KeyError(u'pkgs_dirs',) An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report. Upload successful.

Also, when I opened the Anaconda prompt, and typed anaconda-navigator, I received this error at the end of several file paths:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Then, I deleted the .anaconda and .spyder and .matplotlib folders in C:\Users\aneme.  Then, I uninstalled and reinstall again two times, and, each of those times, Anaconda did not reinstall the navigator, Jupyter or Spyder.  I have scoured online communities for several hours, but I have yet to find a solution.  Thank you.

Comment: What happens now when you try to reinstall? What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: Hi Code-Apprentice.  I reinstalled again, and I have the same problem as I did when I could find the Anaconda Navigator but it would not open.  I opened the Anaconda prompt and typed anaconda-navigator, and I received this error at the end of several file paths:  ImportError:  DLL load failed:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Also, when I try to create a Conda environment in PyCharm, I receive this error:  Failed to Create Interpreter  Executed command:  Conda C:\Users\aneme\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda.exe create -p  C:\Users\aneme\Anaconda2\envs\untitled -y python=2.7  KeyError: u'pkgs_dirs'.  This is followed by a long list of files paths, and it ends with environmental variables:  conda info could not be constructed. KeyError(u'pkgs_dirs',)  An unexpected error has occurred.  Conda has prepared the above report.  Upload successful.

Comment: You should [edit] your question with those details.

Comment: Thanks Code-Apprentice.  I edited the question.  I tried to upload images, but apparently I need reputation points.  First question on StackOverflow.  Any suggestions about what to read or what to do regarding this problem?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Anaconda or conda. The little I have worked with it, I haven't run into these problems. I am just trying to help you improve your question so that it provides the information necessary to allow someone to answer it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.